# Prove $\mathbb{E}[M^{-1}]$ of a matrix-variate Gaussian random variable $M$ does not exist

Tags: probability-theory

Let $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a matrix-variate Gaussian random variable, meaning 
$$\vec{M} \sim \mathcal{N}(\vec{M_0}, \Sigma)
$$
where $\vec{\cdot}$ denotes the vectorization operator, stacking the rows of a matrix into a vector of dimension $n^2$ and $\vec{M_0} \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ and $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2\times n^2}$ symmetric positive definite. I am trying to prove the following conjecture:

> **Conjecture**: Assume $\vec{M} \sim \mathcal{N}(\vec{M_0}, \Sigma)$, then $\mathbb{E}[M^{-1}]$ does not exist.

This is straight-forward to prove in the univariate case ($n=1$):

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \left[\lvert{M^{-1}\rvert} \right] &\propto \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lvert{x}\rvert} \exp{\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}} \, dx = 2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} p(x) \, dx\\
&= 2 \int_0^{1} \frac{1}{x} p(x) \, dx + 2 \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} p(x) \, dx\\
&\geq 2 \underbrace{\min_{\xi \in [0,1]} p(\xi)}_{> 0} \int_0^{1} \frac{1}{x} \, dx + 2 \int_1^{\infty} \underbrace{\frac{1}{x} p(x)}_{\geq 0} \, dx = \infty.
\end{align}
$$
However, I have trouble extending this result to arbitrary $n$. Note, that $M$ is almost surely invertible. My approach was to try to leverage the univariate case either via induction or by block matrix inversion
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}{A}& {b}\\{b}^T & c \end{bmatrix} \implies
M^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
\left( {A}- \frac{ 1}{ c}{b}{ b}^T \right)^{-1} &
-\frac{1}{k}{A}^{-1}{b}\\
-\frac{1}{k}{ b}^T{ A}^{-1} &
\frac{ 1}{ k}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with $k = c-{b}^T{A}^{-1}{b}$. If we can show that $\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{k}]$ does not exist we are done. However, $\frac{1}{k}$ is not normally distributed, hence we cannot use the above. Does anybody have ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Are you assuming that $M$ is symmetric?

Comment: Not in general, but I’d be interested in a proof for a Gaussian measure over just symmetric matrices also. I suppose you could just stack the entries in and below the diagonal into a vector and define a Gaussian distribution over them.